# Hyphenated terms in KDB WHERE clause list

Tags: where-clause, kdb

I'm trying to list hyphenated criteria in a KDB WHERE IN list. The single (non-hyphenated) terms work just fine but when I need to have a hyphen in the literal, KDB doesn't like it. I've tried quoting the strings in a comma delimited list but that doesn't seem to work either.

**This works just fine:**

```
where product in (`CD`MUNICIPAL)
```

**This gives me an error:**

```
where product in (`TREASURY-NOTE`TREASURY-BOND`TREASURY-TIPS)
```

**Error:**

```
'TIPS
```

**This is what I'm trying but with no luck:**

```
where product in ("TREASURY-NOTE","TREASURY-BOND","TREASURY-TIPS")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because "-" is a special character you need to declare these as strings before casting to symbols.

```
where product in `$("TREASURY-NOTE";"TREASURY-BOND";"TREASURY-TIPS")
```

You could also use "like" which allows you to use some basic regex:

```
where product like "TREASURY*"
```